# Dropout: scaling the activation versus inverting the alpha dropout

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, dropout

I have the same question as in this post:
[Dropout: scaling the activation versus inverting the dropout](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205932/dropout-scaling-the-activation-versus-inverting-the-dropout)
but for [alpha dropouts](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.02515.pdf): I would like to know if I need to apply the scale factor of $p$ when applying a prediction (not the training)?